# embedded swf file height/width in html

Tags: html, css

I am  embedding s a very small speaker icon icon as in the url    http://media.photobucket.com/image/animated%20speaker/corleonefred/SOL/ZAAO/animated_speaker.gif?o=7
But when the flash is loaded the height and width of the swf file is much more that specified in the html tag.How is this to be resolved

```
<div style="display: inline;float:center;">
      <OBJECT
                                 classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
                                 WIDTH="4"
                                 HEIGHT="4"
                                 id="myMovieName">

                               <PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE="mysound.swf" />
                               <PARAM NAME="quality" VALUE="high" />
                               <PARAM NAME="bgcolor" VALUE="#FFFFFF" />

                               <EMBED
                                  href="mysound.swf"
              src="mysound.swf"
              flashvars="soundUrl=/var/mychannel/sound.mp3"
                                  quality=high
                                  bgcolor=#FFFFFF
                                  NAME="myMovieName"
                                  ALIGN=""
                                  TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash">
                               </EMBED>
                               </OBJECT>
```

Comment: AFAIK there's no float: center;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify Width & Height attributes in the `<embed>` section too.